# Создать массив чисел со строки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Помогите пожалуйста создать массив чисел со строки. Я пробовал, но результат не порадовал:

```js
var str = "[1.11, 0.0, 1.37, 1.8, 5.37, 0.16, 90.19]";
var array1 = Array.from(str.split(','),Number);  
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: а если попробовать window.eval('var array1=' +str)? вам же просто надо эту строку как массив представить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "[1.11, 0.0, 1.37, 1.8, 5.37, 0.16, 90.19]";
const array = str.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '')
  .split(/[, ]+/)
  .map(Number.parseFloat)

console.log(array)
```

... или так:

```js
var str = "[1.11, 0.0, 1.37, 1.8, 5.37, 0.16, 90.19]";

// Просто находим все числа
const array = str.match(/[\d\.]+/g).map(Number)
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 4):

Боги дали нам волшебный метод [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), пользуйся им:

```js
var str = "[1.11, 0.0, 1.37, 1.8, 5.37, 0.16, 90.19]";
var array1 = JSON.parse(str);  
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Ха, ха. Точно, это же JSON.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, вариант со сплитом тоже вполне вариант - когда JSON только частично валидный, и стандартный парсинг об него ломается :) ведь у метода `parse` есть особенность бросать ошибку при некорректных данных. Правда, я бы чуть иначе разбирал: `str.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').split(',').map(Number)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "[1.11, 0.0, 1.37, 1.8, 5.37, 0.16, 90.19]";
/* но если данные из нестабильного источника, лучше проверить: */
if(!/^\[\d+(.\d+)?(e-?\d+)?(,\s*\d+(.\d+)?(e-?\d+)?)*\]$/i.test(str)){
   throw new SyntaxError('before eval: '+str);
}
var arr = eval(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативным подходом может стать использование метода [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), который позволит собрать все числа в массив

Для этого можно определить регулярное выражение для чисел, например

```
/\d+(\.\d+)?/
```

В итоге можно получить следующий код:

```js
var str = "[1.11, 0.0, 1.37, 1.8, 5.37, 0.16, 90.19]";
const array = str.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g)
  .map(Number)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Ты опоздал, буквально на 3 мин.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, Grundy всегда вовремя :) у тебя не совсем корректная регулярка внутри `match` :)

Comment: Не, не. Это твоя некорректная https://regex101.com/r/4T7Cv9/1. Хотя и моя не совсем.